# How to use FAXCOMLib in windows service ?

Tags: c#, windows-7, fax

I implemented a program for sending fax messages. I use FAXCOMLib and it works when I call it in windows forms. Now I want to call it in windows service, and this is my problem.

The code is simple:

```
            FaxServer faxServer = new FaxServer();
            faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName);

            object obj = faxServer.CreateDocument("D:\\test.bmp");
            FaxDoc fd = (FaxDoc)obj;

            fd.FaxNumber = "123xxxxx";
            fd.RecipientName = "Tester";
            fd.DisplayName = "TestFax";
            fd.SenderName = "Annadurai";

            int i = fd.Send();

            lp.Debug("Sent" + i.ToString()); // Log fax id 

            faxServer.Disconnect();
```

I both ways, code returns an id, but in windows forms fax is added to "Windows Fax and Scan", in windows service - NOT. Why? What should I do to make it works ?

I use Windows 7.

Comment: I think, that could be caused by the fact that the service windows has no UI? IF this is right, what should I do, to send fax through windows service ?

Comment: No exceptions is thrown? while debugging you getting id after send()?

Comment: Yep, no exception, Send() returns id. But nothing in Outbox :/

Comment: Yeah programming for Windows Fax sux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation  it appears that FAXCOMLIB only works on desktop applications:

`Applies to: desktop apps only`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692375(v=vs.85).aspx

Desktop app only is a poor description as it implies anything but Web Apps. I have the following code running in a console app and it works fine so apparently that counts as desktop:

```
    FaxServer server = new FaxServer();
    server.Connect("");
    FaxDoc document = server.CreateDocument(@"C:\RHDSetup.log");
    document.FaxNumber = @"111-111-1111";
    long jobId = document.Send();
```

Comment: Would it work in a Windows service? I need to do this on an upcoming project.

Comment: I didn't try, but since I was able to get it working on a console app, I think you will be fine to make it work in a service.

Comment: It doesn't work in windows service.