# FAXCOMLib is not working in windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, fax, winfax

I want to send fax from computer, I am using FAXCOMLib. It is working on windows based application, but it is not working on windows service.

I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793507/how-to-use-faxcomlib-in-windows-service) across which shows that FAXCOMLIb will not work on windows server.

Is that true?
If yes.

Can any body let me know how to send fax using windows service?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The Fax service since Vista is very sensitive to the user account that's used for the service.  The default one (System) is unlikely to work, pick a regular user account or create a dedicated one for just the service.  Ask questions about it at serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks for your help... It helps to resolve the issue. After logged with user account it works.